# How can I tighten security?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

A couple of times, when I've been tasked with locating rebel scum within the Death Star, I received a message saying that the hero had escaped my clutches (even though I tracked him down). **How can I prevent this from happening?**

[image: Tiny Death Star screenshot showing popup window]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot. However, you still get 1 Bux if they escape. Catching them gives 2.

This changed with the Imperial levels update.

Answer (score 10):

You can't. However, the hero eacaping gives you two Bux instead of one (presumably to tighten security), so it's a good thing.

Comment: Ya it seems like security goes from 0% to 50% with each spy the more you do it, as in they always escape the first few times, but after a while, it's a push.